# How to download ONE image from remote server and display in ANDROID (CLOSED)

Tags: android, eclipse, download

Currently I'm trying to download an image which is stored in my server directory. But I don't know why my app still display that image even though that image is replace with another image.

Meaning that firstly I upload image1, then I can load image1. when image1 is replace by image2, the app still show image1.

Im not sure where is my error. Does it lies in the code or other reason. Needed some help!

**Below is my code:**

```
button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View view) {
        new download().execute();
    }
});

class download extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... path) {
        String outPut = null;
        String s = "http://url/image/img_123.jpg";
        URL myFileUrl = null;
        try {
            myFileUrl = new URL(s);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) myFileUrl
                    .openConnection();
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.connect();
            int length = conn.getContentLength();
            int[] bitmapData = new int[length];
            byte[] bitmapData2 = new byte[length];
            InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();

            bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);

            outPut = "success";
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return outPut;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // updating UI from Background Thread
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                imageView1.setImageBitmap(bm);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

```
button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View view) {
        // new download().execute();
        Drawable drawable = LoadImageFromWeb("http://url/image/img_123.jpg");
        imageView1.setImageDrawable(drawable);
    }
});

private Drawable LoadImageFromWeb(String url) {
    try {
        InputStream is = (InputStream) new URL(url).getContent();
        Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "src name");
        return d;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exc="+e);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one example which help to download image file from URL and it store your custom location, by which you can display on screen after download 
http://getablogger.blogspot.in/2008/01/android-download-image-from-server-and.html

**Update:**

I think you need to load image direcly from url..see here 
http://progrnotes.blogspot.in/2010/09/url.html

Comment: im using that code. but this code like can only download image one time. as in when the image is replace by another image. when i refresh, the new image wont change.

Comment: so i think you need to directly load from server

Comment: but i need to display the image on the android application

Comment: have you give permission of writeExternalStoreage

Comment: i updated the new code. what do you mean by give permission to write external storage

Comment: @user1671148 U didnt say whats the error in the above code. Could be only a comment, not an answer.

Comment: I can only load the image once. if the image is changed, the app still load the first image even though it is being replaced in the server. No error is shown in the logcat

Comment: remove `System.out.println("Exc="+e);` and write e.printstacktrace();