# Loading an image URL from a string in android

Tags: android

I have stored an image URL in a String and now I want to display that image from it.

```
NodeList BannerImage            = document.getElementsByTagName( "Banner_List" );
Node banner_node                = BannerImage.item( 0 );
String banner                   = banner_node.getTextContent( );
ArrayList< String > arrayBANNER = new ArrayList< String >( );  

arrayBANNER.add( banner ); 
for(int i=0;i<arrayBANNER.indexOf(banner);i++)
{
    arrayBANNER.add(banner);
}
```

and this is the XML:

```
<Banner>
  <Banner_Image>http://www.metromatinee.com/agile_dogs/01.jpg</Banner_Image>
  <Banner_Name>72 Model:</Banner_Name>
  <Banner_Id>3740</Banner_Id>
</Banner>
<Banner>
  <Banner_Image>http://www.metromatinee.com/agile_dogs/02.jpg</Banner_Image>
  <Banner_Name>AKAM</Banner_Name>
  <Banner_Id>3491</Banner_Id>
</Banner>
<Banner>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this you can try with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15219595/downloading-images-from-server-and-displaying-them-on-imageview-of-listview) or [How to download ONE image from remote server and display in ANDROID (CLOSED)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12616026/how-to-download-one-image-from-remote-server-and-display-in-android-closed)

Comment: _@chaitanya i stored the image url in an arraylist,  iwant to display it from the array list any help

Comment: Use this for(int i=0;i<arrayBANNER.size();i++)
{
 
    Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("Your array list index for image ");

    ImageView myImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageviewTest);
    myImage.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);

}

Answer (score 0):

you can use the framework called AQuerry (http://code.google.com/p/android-query/)
It can be used even in commercial apps, and it has lots of features and effects for images, including caching and lazy loading and stuff like that.

To see demos of what you can do with the framework, download the app with examples from google play.

Hope this helps :)